# Robotframework: how to show passed test as "PASS" even if suite teardown were "Fail"

Tags: robotframework

I use robot framework at following environment.

- Python 2.7.6
- robotframework 2.8.7
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

I use robotframwork like this.

```
*** settings ***
Suite Setup       setupkeyword # Provisioning for test
Suite Teardown    teardownkeyword # Delete all resources

*** testcases ***
TestCase1
TestCase2
TestCase3...
```

In this case,
if Teardown fails, test case is shown Failed in report like followings.

```
Suite Setup:PASS
Suite Teardown:FAIL
TestCase1:FAIL
TestCase2:FAIL
TestCase3:FAIL
```

But Teardown is not the purpose of this test,
So I want report shows like followings.

```
Suite Setup:PASS
Suite Teardown:FAIL
TestCase1:PASS
TestCase2:PASS
TestCase3:PASS
```

I test like followings.

```
Suite Teardown    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    teardownkeyword # Delete all resources
```

But in this case, report shows

```
Suite Teardown:PASS
```

but I want to know whether Teardown was passed or not.

Is there any good method for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best method would be to redesign teardown keyword to give a warn when it is about to fail (but avoid failure). It can be accomplished with log keyword:

```
Log    This keyword would fail due a some reason    level=WARN
```

you could try with level=ERROR (maybe it won't fail whole test suite then?)

Comment: sorry for late. Thank you. so I should modify teardownkeyword to check fail or pass and if fails do LOG keyword like you shows me. I try it. Thank you!